# FirstName.Val() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to take the inputs from a user details form and put them into an array calles requestData, i get `.val()` is not a function when i am creating an array with the following code

**Jquery**

```
 $('#submit').click(function () {                
            var requestData = {
               FirstName: FirstName.val(),
               LastName: LastName.val()                  
            }
```

**My Html is**

```
<form role="form">
            <br style="clear:both">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Enter Your Details</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="LastName" id="LastName"  placeholder="Last Name" required>
            </div>           

<button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone see what i have done wrong?

Comment: What are FirstName and LastName?

Comment: It would seem as though FirstName is not a jquery object, where do you initialize FirstName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
 $('#submit').click(function () {                
        var requestData = {
           FirstName: $("#FirstName").val(),
           LastName: $("#LastName").val()
        }
```

Also you can trim the text:

```
 $('#submit').click(function () {                
        var requestData = {
           FirstName: $("#FirstName").val().trim(),
           LastName: $("#LastName").val().trim()
        }
```